# Urysohn Metrization Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Given a topological space $X$ which is normal (every two disjoint closed sets of X have disjoint open neighborhoods) and second countable. Let $\{U_n\}$ be a countable base for the topology and define
$$A = \bigg\{(n,m)\in \mathbb N\times \mathbb N\; \bigg|\; \overline {U_n}\subset U_m\bigg\},$$
$f_{n,m}$ is the continuous function such that $f\equiv 0$ on $\overline{U_n}$ and $f\equiv 1$ on $X\setminus U_m$. We define the following metric
$$\rho(x,y) := \sum_{(n,m)\in A} \frac{1}{2^{n+m}} |f_{n,m} (x) - f_{n,m}(y)|.$$

I want to check the topology induced by above metric is indeed the given topology on $X$.

1. For each $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $U_n$ that contains $x$ and $U_n \subset B_\rho (x, \epsilon)$.

This follows from $\rho(x,y)$ is a continuous function of $y$ since it is the uniform limit of continuous functions (of $y$).

2. If $U_n$ contains $x$, there is an $\epsilon > 0$ for which $B_\rho(x,\epsilon) \subset U_n$

How would I approach this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got it.

Given $x\in U_k$ for some $U_k$ in the base, since $X$ is normal, $\{x\}$ is closed and there exists 
$$\{x\}\subset U_l \subset \overline {U_l} \subset U_k,$$
and we have $(l,k)\in A$.

Now let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2^{l+k}}$, if $\rho(x,y) <\epsilon$, then we have 
$$\epsilon > \rho(x,y) = \sum_{(n,m)\in A} \frac{1}{2^{n+m}} |f_{n,m}(x) - f_{n,m}(y)| \geq \frac{1}{2^{l+k}} |f_{l,k}(x) - f_{l,k}(y)|$$
this implies
$$|f_{l,k}(x) - f_{l,k}(y)| = |0-f_{l,k}(y)| = f_{l,k}(y) <1$$
from construction, we must have $y\in U_k$.

Answer (score 0):

Pervin = Pervin, W.J.: Foundations of General Topology, New York, Academic Press, 1964.
Your question is answered by Pervin [Proof of Urysohn's Metrization Theorem, p.160, l.12-l.19]. For other related topics of Urysohn's Metrization Theorem, read Example 6.170 of https://sites.google.com/view/lcwangpress/%E9%A6%96%E9%A0%81/papers/mathematical-methods.